# Laravel5 render html::linkroute

Tags: php, laravel

i am using html::linkroute however the link  tag and contents are being put on the screen rather than rendered, is this a bug?

The code i am using

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('admin.users.edit', $user->display_name, array($user->id)) }}
```

the output in the browser

```
<a href="http://localhost/laravel/admin/users/1/edit">Prof. Trent D'Amore</a>
```

Comment: Dont watch laravel4 videos and then use laravel5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5 `{{ ... }}` escapes the output, thats why you see the HTML in the browser. Instead you should use `{!! ... !!}` which will render the raw output to the browser. So this will work:

```
{!! HTML::linkRoute('admin.users.edit', $user->display_name, array($user->id)) !!}
```

You can read more about [Laravel 5 Blade changes](https://laravel-news.com/2014/09/laravel-5-0-blade-changes/).